# children are reactive, but children of children are not reactive - vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When I have following data.

```
private static _docFields: TreeData[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      id: NodeType.Annotation,
      label: 'Annotations',
      children: [],
    },
```

and if I do following, it is reactive.

```
ApiService.post(
          'documentAnnotation/annotations', { projectId: AppStore.projectId },
        ).then((responseData: KeyValue[]) => {
          // TODO: Can't there be a mapper which can transform the results?
          responseData.forEach((documentAnnotation) => {

            AppStore.docFields.find((x) => x.id === NodeType.Annotation)!.children!.push({
              label: documentAnnotation.value,
              value: documentAnnotation.key,
            });

          });
        });
```

But when I have following data,

```
private static _docFields: TreeData[] = [
    {
      id: '0.' + NodeType.Annotation,
      label: 'Annotations',
      nodeType: NodeType.Annotation,
      children: [{
        id: '0.' + NodeType.SinglePageAnnotation,
        label: 'Single',
        children: [],
        nodeType: NodeType.SinglePageAnnotation,
      }, {
        id: '0.' + NodeType.MultiPageAnnotation,
        label: 'Multiple',
        children: [],
        nodeType: NodeType.MultiPageAnnotation,
      }],
    },
```

and I do following, it is not reactive. what I need to do?

```
AppStore.docFields
        .find((x) => x.nodeType === NodeType.Annotation)!.children!
        .find((y) => y.nodeType === NodeType.SinglePageAnnotation)!.children!.push({
                  label: documentAnnotation.value,
                  value: documentAnnotation.key,
                });
```

I have bound element UI tree as following.

```
<el-tree :data="AppStore.docFields">
```